# Sending strings from processing to arduino

Tags: arduino, serial-port, processing

I'm trying to set up communications between my PC, and my Arduino with the Processing environment, but the Arduino doesn't seem to be getting any of the messages I send. I doubled checked, and I know I can receive messages from the Arduino, but I can't send anything back. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here's my test code for processing:

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;

void setup(){
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
}

void draw(){
  myPort.write("test");
  while (myPort.available() > 0) {
    String inByte = myPort.readString();
    println(inByte);
  }
}
```

Here's my test code for the Arduino:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

String data;
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  //Serial.println("is running");
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the incoming byte:
    data = Serial.readString();

    // say what you got:
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.println(data);
  }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get! Thanks!

Comment: While that's true, the draw() function loops repeatedly until the program stops, so even if it misses the first serial message, it'll get the next one.

Comment: Ah, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after looking into several different posts on the Arduino forum, I figured out what the problem is. The function processing uses to send data over serial does not automatically include a return character at the end of the string. This is important because the Arduino won't read from the serial buffer until it sees that return character. All I had to do was add "\r\n" to the end of each string I sent over serial, and that solved the problem!

Comment: `Serial.readString()` doesn't wait for newline characters. It just waits until it gets nothing for 1 second. If this worked for you then you have different code on the Arduino than in your question. Are you using `readStringUntil`?

Comment: No, I'm just using readString on the Arduino. I wasn't getting any communication until I added that return character to the end.